# Array_Map using multiple native callbacks?

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-map

I want to run 3 native functions on the same array: `trim`, `strtoupper` and `mysql_real_escape_string`. Can this be done?

Trying to pass an array as a callback like this isn't working:

```
$exclude = array_map(array('trim','strtoupper','mysql_real_escape_string'), explode("\n", variable_get('gs_stats_filter', 'googlebot')));
```

Although this works fine because it's only using one native function as the callback:

```
$exclude = array_map('trim', explode("\n", variable_get('gs_stats_filter', 'googlebot')));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to do it like this:

```
$exclude = array_map(function($item) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper(trim($item)));
}, explode("\n", variable_get('gs_stats_filter', 'googlebot')));
```

Comment: That's what I had figured; that I'd need to end up writing a separate function for the callback. Unfortunately I'm still stuck on PHP 5.2.17 so I had to make a non-anonymous function, BUT, it still works great. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 5):

You could also do something like:

```
  $exclude = array_map(function($item) {
     return trim(strtoupper(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
  }, explode(...));
```

or something. Pass in an anonymous function that does all that stuff.

Hope that helps.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just pass the result of one mapping into another:

```
$result = array_map(
    'mysql_real_escape_string',
    array_map(
        'trim',
        array_map(
            'strtoupper',
            $your_array
        )
    )
);
```

You can also use a callback in PHP 5.3+:

```
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strtoupper($x)));
}, $your_array);
```

or earlier (in versions of PHP lower than 5.3):

```
$result = array_map(
    create_function('$x','return mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strtoupper($x)));'),
    $your_array
);
```

Comment: @TimCooper: I am showing possible solutions - there are at least 3 of them, if `array_map` has to be used. But yes, indeed PHP makes it not optimal, because it walks the array (each time it is different) 3 times and returns whole array 3 times.